# does Tango provide linear positioning?

Tags: google-project-tango

Orientation is a fairly solved problem in android, and Tango does better with the help of visual aid.

but linear positioning based purely on inertial navigation is terrible , due to the need of double integration, and the relative lower quality of MEMS accelerometers.

what is the quality of linear positioning by Tango ? for example , drift within 1m per hour?

Thanks
Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, both rotational and positional tracking are very high quality in my experience (centimeter-level). However, there's an annoying bug (apparently not cause by Tango but by Android 4.4's sensor drivers) that *occasionally* causes rapid drifting. Very annoying. Here's a write-up of the problem: https://plus.google.com/+ChuckKnowledge/posts/dVk4ZgVikgT

I'm hoping this will go away by itself in consumer-grade devices (which will obviously use later versions of Android), but it's something to consider even now. Most importantly, it can happen when I demo Tango to others, and it obviously kills the experience.